# How do you download mods on Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I was wondering how to download mods for AGES! I know I may sound like I don't know ANYTHING about MineCraft but, you see, I watch all the videos and descriptions about *how to download mods* but I STILL DONT GET IT! If you want to know what computer I have, its a windows DELL one. I am currently (obviously) using vanilla and trying to find lots of *only one command* videos. PLEASE HELP!

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to download mods, but the easiest one is:

1. Download Forge for your Minecraft version.
2. Search for your favorite mod corresponding to your forge version.
3. Some mods come with direct installers, in this case just run the install file.
4. For other mods, make a folder named Mods in your .minecraft folder, and extract the mod to it.
5. Run Minecraft and select your forge profile, your mods will now be loaded.

Some mods have other ways of installing them, but the creators then provide you with a video on how to install.